# Why is systemd periodically reloading dnsmasq-dns service?

Tags: centos, systemd, systemctl, dnsmasq

The dnsmask-dns process is reloading every 12 min (approx) on the device.
This is a Centos device.

```
grep Reloaded.Dnsm /var/log/systemd.log


Feb 20 15:46:21 xxxx systemd[1]: Reloaded Dnsmasq DNS server..
Feb 20 15:57:38 xxxx systemd[1]: Reloaded Dnsmasq DNS server..
Feb 20 16:11:28 xxxx systemd[1]: Reloaded Dnsmasq DNS server..
Feb 20 16:23:27 xxxx systemd[1]: Reloaded Dnsmasq DNS server..
```

I looked at the output of currently active systemd timers and find none

```
systemctl list-timers --all
Mon 2023-02-20 14:00:00 AWST  43min left   Mon 2023-02-20 13:00:01 AWST  16min ago    thd_summary_last3.timer      thd_summary_last3.service
Mon 2023-02-20 14:00:00 AWST  43min left   Mon 2023-02-20 13:00:01 AWST  16min ago    thd_summary_last7.timer      thd_summary_last7.service
Mon 2023-02-20 17:20:31 AWST  4h 3min left Sun 2023-02-19 17:20:31 AWST  19h ago      systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Tue 2023-02-21 02:10:00 AWST  12h left     Mon 2023-02-20 11:28:25 AWST  1h 48min ago purge.timer                  purge.service
Tue 2023-02-21 02:30:00 AWST  13h left     Mon 2023-02-20 02:30:00 AWST  10h ago      update-thd-filters.timer     update-thd-filters.service
Tue 2023-02-21 03:00:00 AWST  13h left     Mon 2023-02-20 03:00:00 AWST  10h ago      security_db_update.timer     security_db_update.service
Tue 2023-02-21 03:30:00 AWST  14h left     Mon 2023-02-20 03:30:00 AWST  9h ago       thd_summary_last30.timer     thd_summary_last30.service
Sun 2023-02-26 14:00:00 AWST  6 days left  Sun 2023-02-19 14:00:00 AWST  23h ago      update-geoip-db.timer        update-geoip-db.service
```

also none in crontab as well

```
root@10.60.51.215#crontab -l
no crontab for root
```

not sure what is triggering this

Answer (score 1):

Does the system have any network interfaces configured using DHCP?

The renewal of a DHCP lease might (theoretically) include updated DNS server information, and so the DHCP client might trigger a reload of the DNS configuration, including reloading the `dnsmasq` DNS server (just in case it uses DHCP-provided DNS servers).